# JMS Destination property definitions

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am getting details about ActiveMQ destinations using ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker. However, I couldn't find a source for definitions for below properties.

- Size
- Producer Count
- Average Enqueue Time
- Average Message Size
- Broker ID
- Broker Name
- Consumer Count
- Dequeue Count
- Destination Name
- Dispatch Count
- Enqueue Count
- Expired Count
- Inflight Count
- Max Enqueue Count
- Memory Limit
- Memory Percent Usage
- Memory Usage
- Messages Cached
- Min Enqueue Time

Can someone provide me simple but accurate definitions or meanings of these terms ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details are collected from several online references to ActiveMQ documentation, StackOverflow, blogs, mailing lists etc. Expecting expert comments or reviews regarding this answer for the verification since it was difficult to find a direct trustful resource related to this topic.

[JMS Broker Attribute definitions](http://lwtucs.blogspot.com/2016/10/activemq-broker-attribute-definitions.html)

[JMS Queue Attribute definitions](http://lwtucs.blogspot.com/2016/10/activemq-queue-attribute-definitions.html)

[JMS Message Attribute definitions](http://lwtucs.blogspot.com/2016/10/activemq-message-attribute-definitions.html)